# modeling a beta-binomial regression

Tags: r, statistics

Assume this easy example:

```
treatment <- factor(rep(c(1, 2), c(43, 41)), levels = c(1, 2),labels = c("placebo", "treated"))
improved <- factor(rep(c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), c(29, 7, 7, 13, 7, 21)),levels = c(1, 2, 3),labels = >c("none", "some", "marked"))
numberofdrugs<-rpois(84, 50)+1
healthvalue<-rpois(84,5)
y<-data.frame(healthvalue,numberofdrugs, treatment, improved)
test<-lm(healthvalue~numberofdrugs+treatment+improved, y)
```

What am I supossed to do when I'd like to estimate a beta-binomial regression with R? Is anybody familiar with it? Any thought is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see how this example relates to beta-binomial regression (i.e., you have generated count data, rather than (number out of total possible)).  To simulate beta-binomial data, see `rbetabinom` in *either* the `emdbook` or the `rmutil` packages ...

`library(sos); findFn("beta-binomial")` finds a number of useful starting points, including

- aod (analysis of overdispersed data), `betabin` function
- `betabinomial` family in `VGAM`
- `hglm` package
- `emdbook` package (for `dbetabinom`) plus `mle2` package

Comment: Hello! Thanks fot the input. I wasn't sure about if it is neccessary to have "number out of totals". For better understanding to the readers here is a similar discussion: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11876/fitting-a-beta-binomial-model-in-the-case-of-overdispersion-in-r